# Drawable createFromPath returns null even though file exists

Tags: java, android, drawable

```
d = Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+filenameString);
System.err.println(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+filenameString+"  -  "+d);
image.setImageDrawable(d);
```

this above is the code i'm using to get the `drawable` and below the `Logcat`:

```
04-09 15:34:44.005: I/System.out(20814): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
04-09 15:34:44.010: I/System.out(20814): buffer returned 
04-09 15:34:44.010: D/skia(20814): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
04-09 15:34:44.010: W/System.err(20814): /storage/sdcard0/1396850896.482724.png
04-09 15:34:44.010: W/System.err(20814):   -  null
```

i checked and the file exists.

i've set **`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`** and **`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`**.

Comment: try to open its input stream, maybe you dont have read permissions to that file

Comment: i've tried that just before reading this message XD i used:

in = (InputStream) new URL("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+filenameString).getContent();

but it gives me FileNotFoundException even though it's there...

Comment: try to open FileInputStream